# Facebook messenger "Get started" button does not appear

Tags: facebook, messenger

I follow [Facebook messenger tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button) to create "Get Started" button when user first chat with page but the button does not appear (I haven't had a conversation before)

```
$params = array(
     "setting_type" => "call_to_actions",
     "thread_state" => "new_thread",
     "call_to_actions" => array(
         0 => array(
            'payload' => 'welcome'
         )
      )
);
```

I've got response

```
Array ( [result] => Successfully added new_thread's CTAs )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be because you are not using the write webhook to make that postback work. In the webhook section on your app you have to check the option messaging_postback.